# Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1 Error when archiving

Tags: archiving, libraries, xcode, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to archive a project to submit it to the iOS App Store, but keep getting this problem. I have already set yes to the skip install option, re-installed Xcode, rebooted and re-copied my libraries, as well as edited my schemes. I've done my research and tried everything suggested, but still get this error.

Does anybody has a suggestion?

`chown: /Users/Samuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safari-clksdtmdmbdyrefxcltqlpejzefv/ArchiveIntermediates/Branon/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/i386: No such file or directory
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1`

Comment: The complete error is slightly too long to put in a comment (700 characters).  It's available on this paste bin: http://pastebin.com/dMkMHSzm

Comment: Here your message complains about i386, on pastebin it's armv6? And your app is named Safari?

Comment: Hi.  When it was complaining about i386, I removed the i386 architecture from the App, along with the reference to iphonesimulator (thinking this would solve the problem as it only needed to be built for ARMv6/7).  When I did this, it started complaining about the ARMv6 architecture.  Any ideas?